# Replace characters at end of string, until it reaches a certain character regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

lets say my string is this, which may have white space at the end.

```
var s = "<a href="/FOO/tags/EDM">EDM</a>/ <a href="/FOO/tags/EDM">EDM</a>/ / / /  "
```

I want to replace every instance of the / after the last closing anchor tag. Here's what I've tried:

```
s.replace(/[</a>](.*)$/, '');
```

but not getting the expeted results, could I please have some detailed explanations on why/what I'm doing wrong?

Thankyou!

Comment: So everything after the last closing anchor tag pretty much?

Comment: You want to replace with what?... Or do you want to remove? Please provide and example of the output.

Comment: Please wrap your variable in single quotes.

Comment: @NabilKadimi, Sorry about the double quotes, just wrote out this example quickly, and I'm just replacing the result with nothing (see my replace code in my op)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<\/a>(\/\s*)+$` with `</a>`.

### Snippet

```js
var s = '<a href="/FOO/tags/EDM">EDM</a>/ <a href="/FOO/tags/EDM">EDM</a>/ / / /  ';

window.alert( 
  "Before:\n" + s + "\n\n\n"
  + "After:\n" + s.replace(/<\/a>(\/\s*)+$/, '</a>')
);
```

### Explanation

- `<\/a>` matches `</a>`
- `(\/\s*)` matches `\` followed by optional white space
- `+` matches previous as many times as it exists
- `$` makes sure nothing is found after the last `\(plus optional white space)`

### Another demo

**Demo**:
http://regex101.com/r/yA0aS0/1

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
(^.*<\/a>)|.*$
```

and replace with `$1`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qK3wI3/3)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  ^             # Start of string/line
  .             # Any character except line break
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  <             # "<"
  \/            # "/"
  a>            # "a>"
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
|               # OR
.               # Any character except line break
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```